# Using large non-bazel dependencies in a bazel project

Tags: bazel

I would like to use a very large non-bazel system in a bazel project. Specifically, [ROS2](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki). This dependency provides a large number of python, C, and C++ libraries which are built using its own hand-rolled buildsystem. Obviously, I would like to avoid having to translate the entire buildsystem over to bazel.

Broadly, what's the best way of me doing this? In instinct was to use a custom repository rule to download the source (since it's split across many repositories), then use a `genrule` to call the ROS2 build system. Then write my simple `cc_import` and `py_library` rules for each of the individual components that I need.

However, I'm having trouble with the bit where I need to call the foreign build system. It seems that `genrule`s require a list of output files to be specified, while I would like it to make an entire `build` directory available.

Before I spent any more time on this, I thought I'd ask whether I'm on the right lines since I'm new to bazel. Is this a good strategy? How would you approach this problem? Are there any other projects that mainly use bazel, but call other build systems in this way that I can look at?

Comment: Yes, Bazel (not only gen_rule) needs an explicit list of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to build with Bazel.

Comment: @rds I'm afraid I don't understand what details you're looking for that aren't in the question?

Answer (score 1):

As of recent, you can use rules_foreign_cc to call native CMake or make/configure like projects.

Comment: That looks promising, I'll investigate further. Link for the interested: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc